# How to download a document from a webpage with wget

Tags: wget, download, file-types

I have a web page which contains a link to a document. I'm able to download the document by using the following command:

```
wget -r -A.doc www.website.com/1.doc
```

However, I would like to provide the link to the page which contains the document and for `wget` to scan for the document link and download it.

Is there a way to use `wget` to scan for a specific link being a document type?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755229/how-to-download-all-files-but-not-html-from-a-website-using-wget

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work -

```
wget -r -l 2 -A doc,docx,odt http://example.com/page-to-scan.html
```

Recursively get the page at http://example.com/page-to-scan.html and follow all of the links on that page and bring in everything from the next level.  And then throw away anything that doesn't end in .doc,.docx, or .odt (you mention document, so these are the 3 types - MS old, MS current, and Open|Libre Office)

Comment: Thanks, but this only retrieves the folder structure, no document...